# The first four verses of surat Ar-Rahman

Tags: quran, tafseer, surat-ar-rahman

Surat Ar-Rahman begins this way:

> :In the name of the most merciful & gracious God:
>
> :The most merciful::Taught the Quran::Created the human::Taught him
> eloquence:

But "Taught the Quran" to whom? Did God mean teaching it to humans? If yes, why it was mentioned before mentioning the creation of the humans and teaching them eloquence? This sequence seems strange.
If no, then he meant teaching it to whom?

Comment: It isn't being mentioned in chronological order, as can be clearly seen by Ayaat 7 & 10. https://quran.com/55/ . Allah didn't create the heavens and the earth after creating humans did he

Answer (score 3):

The taught has two objects: first object is missed (Teaching Quran to whom?), the second object is Quran. This is said **Taghdir** in Arabic language. There are some possible forms in this Ayah that interpreters mentioned. Here are them:

> علم الانسان القرآن

Taught the Quran to man

or

> علم الانس و الجن القرآن

Taught the Quran to man and jinn.

Allamah Tabatabie, one of the greatest interpreters of Quran and writer of interpretation **Al-Mizan**, preferred the second interpretation and stated:

In this Surah, man and jinn together is subjected several times and if this teaching were merely for humans, It wouldn't be correct to subject man and jinn again and again in later ayahs.
Beside the point, this order of ayahs implies that **teaching Quran** is the beginning of the count of Allah's blessings. Quran indicates the expression of the paths of happiness, the happiness which is the wish and the purpose of all the seekers, thus placing it ahead of other blessings, and teaching it even ahead of the creation of man and jinn that the Quran has revealed to their teachings.